# Load String or XmlElement in XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have implemented below code which loads string into xmlDocument. I have got a code review comment saying I should use xmlElement instead of string. I want to know people perspective over it. strFreeLegalFee is the string value added to FreeLegalFeeFlag Node.

```
string strReturnXML = "<FREELEGALFEEFLAG>" + strFreeLegalFee + "</FREELEGALFEEFLAG>";
var xmlOutDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode xmlDataNode = null;
//XmlAssist loads string into XmlDocument
xmlOutDoc = XmlAssist.Load(strReturnXML);
```

Comment: why not ask the reviewer about the reason?

Comment: Your `strReturnXML` is a product of string manipulation.  You should instead be using the XML libraries that .NET provides to manipulate an XML document.  There are a lot of nuances to XML and these problems have already been solved for you, not even mentioning how hardcoded strings and managing all the opening and closing tags would lead to errors quite quickly

Comment: What is `strFreeLegalFee`?  Is it some embedded XML, or what?  As it is, without concrete details showing a complete [mcve], we can't really comment.  And even then this might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have updated question. Thank you for your reply and suggestion

Comment: @Abhijit - thanks, but I think we still need to see `XmlAssist.Load()`.